# LookupError: No installed app with label 'mobile_backend/'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using django with app engine and datastore.

I want to test the application, for that I have change my settings for not create a local DB for the test.
in setting.py:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'testing.DatabaselessTestRunner'
```

in testing.py

```
    """Support for testing."""

from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner

class DatabaselessTestRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    """A test suite runner that does not set up and tear down a database."""

    def setup_databases(self):
        """Overrides DjangoTestSuiteRunner"""
        pass

    def teardown_databases(self, *args):
        """Overrides DjangoTestSuiteRunner"""
        pass
```

When I run : python manage.py test mobile_backend/

I have a strange error :

```
raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'mobile_backend/'.
```

But in my setting.py I have add "'mobile_backend'," to my INSTALLED_APPS

Someone can help me?

Thanks

EDIT

the full stack trace of my error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/_doctest.py:59: RemovedInDjango18Warning: The django.test._doctest module is deprecated; use the doctest module from the Python standard library instead.   RemovedInDjango18Warning)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/simple.py:27: RemovedInDjango18Warning: The django.test.simple module and DjangoTestSuiteRunner are deprecated; use django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner instead.   RemovedInDjango18Warning)

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 146, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/simple.py", line 241, in build_suite
    app_config = apps.get_app_config(label)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 150, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label) LookupError: No installed app with label 'mobile_backend/'.
```

Comment: i have the same problem, did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a stray forward slash `/` in your `import` somewhere.

Make sure that you are importing `mobile_backend` rather than `mobile_backend/` in all relevant locations.

Comment: I don't have any slash error in my import. And I never import mobile_backend

Comment: What is the full stack trace of your error? Please edit your question with the full error.

Comment: @mevius I just done the edit. I'm in the same problem